# How to turn ON and OFF logging for specific levels in NLog

Tags: logging, nlog, error-logging

I am using NLog in my application. I want to create a switch in order to turn ON and OFF specific logger levels.

```xml
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="f" />
    <logger levels="Error,Warn,Fatal,Debug,Info" name="CustomLogger" writeTo="database"/>
  </rules>
```

How can I turn off logging for a specific logger level. I do not want to remove it from the below line.

```xml
<logger levels="Error,Warn,Fatal,Debug,Info" name="CustomLogger" writeTo="database"/>
```

How to turn `Info` logging On and OFF using something like this:

```
internalLogLevel="Off"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a final rule that writes the logs to a "blackhole". Add this as the first rule. Turn it off/on with the `enabled` attribute.

e.g. To disable the "info" level, add this as first rule of `<rules>`:

```xml
<logger levels="Info" name="*" writeTo="blackHole" final="true" enabled="true" />
```

and the blackhole target to `<targets>`

```xml
<target name="blackHole" xsi:type="Null" />
```

Comment: Thanks, @Julian. I just solved my problem by setting `enabled` to `true` and `false`. `<logger levels="Info" name="*" writeTo="database" enabled="false" />`

Answer (score 2):

You can assign `GlobalThreshold` like this:

```cs
if (IsProduction)
   NLog.LogManager.GlobalThreshold = NLog.LogLevel.Info;
else
   NLog.LogManager.GlobalThreshold = NLog.LogLevel.Trace;  // No global filter
```

Alternative you can use NLog Layout for the level-filtering in NLog Logging-Rules:

```xml
<nlog>
   <variable name="myLevel" value="Warn" />
    <rules>
      <logger minLevel="${var:myLevel}" writeTo="file" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

```cs
#if DEBUG
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["myLevel"] = "Debug";
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers(); // Explicit refresh of Layouts and updates active Logger-objects
#endif
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages