# Disable SQL logging in ORMLite

Tags: servicestack

How do I turn off SQL logging?

I have NLOG registered like so:

```
  LogManager.LogFactory = new NLogFactory();

  SetConfig(new HostConfig
  {
    AddRedirectParamsToQueryString = true,
    DebugMode = false
  });
```

SQL is being written to log on production and I would like to turn it off.  I am using ORMLite with PostgreSQL  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrmLite logs it's SQL using the configured logger at the Debug log-level, so you'd need to [disable the `Debug` log level in NLog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46361085/85785).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have my own debug messages that are getting hidden in thousands of SQL queries.  I will check NLog to see if I can filter it there based on pattern.